# How to add changes to commit?

Tags: git

I have deleted 4 huge files from my directory and with

git commit -m "added b" 
tried to modify my original commit.
But

```
On branch master
changes not staged for commit:
```

How to perform changes?

Comment: Look up any random resource on git.

Comment: Gee, if only there was a way to `reset` what you've done...

Comment: @MiKibelavista: This is the commant: `git add .` or `git commit -am "XXXX" ` but remember first search on google.

Comment: try `git status` and check if your changes are in green color, if not, type `git add .` and then commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you only removed the files from your sandbox.  You need to remove them from the index before committing:

```
git rm hugefile.1 hugefile.2 hugefile.3 hugefile.4
git commit -m "removed four huge files"
```